# How to get the date modified attribute from a valid directory path using swift on macosx

Tags: macos, swift2

I want to find the date modified of a directory given a valid path.

Something like ls -l -d {path}.

Example:

```
ls -l -d /Volumes/ARCHIVE/DVD\ 1255
drwxr-xr-x@ 1 fmpserver  staff  1214 26 Nov 11:52 /Volumes/ARCHIVE/DVD 1255
```

I think I can get it using NSFileManager.

Code extract:

```
func setStartDate() {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager() ;
    do {
        let attributes:NSDictionary? = try         fileManager.attributesOfFileSystemForPath(self.rootFolder!) ;    
        print("\(attributes)") ;
        if let _attributes = attributes {
            let attribute = _attributes.fileModificatioDate();
                print( attribute ) ;
        }
    } catch  {
        print("Error: \(error)") ;
    }
}
```

Example Output:

According to  [Understanding_Pathnames_in_Swift](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_in_Swift_on_iOS_8#Understanding_Pathnames_in_Swift)

there should be a NSFileModificationDate attribute.

When I run the code I get

```
Optional({
    NSFileSystemFreeNodes = 3016781479;
    NSFileSystemFreeSize = 12356736937984;
    NSFileSystemNodes = 4294883316;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 771751939;
    NSFileSystemSize = 17591842070528;
})
nil
```

Obviously since NSFileModificationDate is not part of the attributes dictionary.

What is the best way to get the date modified attribute from a valid directory path using swift on macosx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attributesOfItemAtPath` rather than `attributesOfFileSystemForPath`

```
do {
  let attributes = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(self.rootFolder!)
  let modificationDate = attributes[NSFileModificationDate] as! NSDate
  print(modificationDate)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

Alternatively you can use also `NSURL`

```
let rootFolderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:self.rootFolder!)
var modificationDate : AnyObject?
do {
  try rootFolderURL.getResourceValue(&modificationDate, forKey: NSURLContentModificationDateKey)
  print(modificationDate as! NSDate)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```